# Pass JsTreeView data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, jstree

I have a list of virtual folder structure. I need to bind that list to JsTreeView. The List may contain something like the below.

**List of Items**

```
Dh
Dh\Sub
Dh\Sub\Another
Dh1
Dh1\Sub1
Dh1\Sub1\Another1
Dh1\Sub1\Another2
```

**Desired Output**

```
Dh
  |______ Sub
             |_____Another
Dh1
  |______ Sub1
             |_____ Another1
             |_____ Another2
```

As, I have tried logic using recursion. But, did not succeed with it. Can anybody tell me how can i achieve this. Any help to the problem will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following class to serialize DB data to  JSON and load into JS Tree View

```
/// <summary>
/// Model which represents data for js tree view
/// </summary>
public class JsTreeViewNode
{
    private int int_id;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "children")]
    public List<JsTreeViewNode> Children { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "a_attr")]
    public AnchorAttribute AAttributes { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int CurrentLevel { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public JsTreeViewNode()
    {
        AAttributes = new AnchorAttribute();
    }

    public JsTreeViewNode(int id)
        : this()
    {
        int_id = id;
        this.Id = int_id.ToString();
        AAttributes.Id = this.Id;
    }

    public int GetNodeId()
    {
        return int_id;
    }

    public JsTreeViewNode Clone()
    {
        var clone = (JsTreeViewNode)this.MemberwiseClone();
        clone.Children = new List<JsTreeViewNode>();
        clone.AAttributes = this.AAttributes.Clone();
        return clone;
    }
}

public class AnchorAttribute
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "draggable")]
    public string Draggable = "false";

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "class", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string CssClassname;

    public virtual AnchorAttribute Clone()
    {
        var clone = (AnchorAttribute)this.MemberwiseClone();
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Children property contains subnodes. Populating them depends on you app logic.

and later in controller

```
public virtual ContentResult LoadTreeData()
{
  var treeData = Repository.GetTreeData();
  return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(treeData), "application/json");
}
```

Hope this helps